# 'Spring' physics

Tags: xna, 2d, xna-4.0, physics

I'm trying to put together a struct or a method of some sort that will allow me to check the relative position between two objects, and if they're too far apart, apply a force that will draw them closer to eachother. I've read that you can achieve this by creating a 'spring', what that might look like in code?

Comment: what about the [first link google suggest when you search "spring physics"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke's_law). it has all the theoretical explanation you need to implement your own or the [second one](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/spring-physics/) explaining how you should implement it step by step. or you can use farseer to simulate spring for you.

Comment: Didn't want to use an entire physics engine for one purpose.

Comment: Technically, a spring's motion would work, but wouldn't it be easier to just change the direction and velocity of the entities until they reach some distance that satisfies the condition? If you're dead set on a spring, here's the Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) on it.

Comment: Naw, not dead set on a spring, so far all the given answers are great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None-physical way (not spring physics):

If I simply wanted an object to pull towards another object and stop there I would use this instead:

Define too far apart as a radius `r`, any object farther than that radius will be attracted to its partner.

```
R = r*r;
```

Lets say the attractor is `A` and the other object is `B`

1. Pick a small percentage representing your speed : s = 25%; `//adjust s as needed`
2. Divide the percentage by 100 : s /= 100.0 `// s = 0.25`
3. Use this method:

`A.attract(B)`

```
deltaT = (currentTime - lastFrameTime) / 1000.0;    //time in seconds since last frame
deltaX = A.x - B.x;
deltaY = A.y - B.y;

if(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY > R)
{
    B.x += s * deltaX * deltaT;
    B.y += s * deltaY * deltaT;
}
//could use some refinement to make the slowdown more gradual.
```

This would attract an object to another without 'letting go' once it gets there.

---

To simulate **spring physics** in one direction, use this:

```
`F=-kx`
```

k is a coefficient and x is the distance between the objects.

F will determine the acceleration speed between object A(attractor) and object B(attracted).

Edit:

Like dreta mentioned, you could use `x` (distance) to help calculate the new speed:

```
// dividing by distance to normalize
B.newVel.x = B.oldVel + ((A.x - B.x) / distance) * F

B.newVel.x = B.oldVel + ((A.x - B.x) / distance) * distance * k
```

Which is basically : (I am taking deltaT, frame time in seconds into account)

```
B.vel.x += (A.x - B.x) * k * deltaT; //You can divide by mass here
B.vel.y += (A.y - B.y) * k * deltaT; //Or adjust k to take that into account
```

---

Otherwise do something like:

To simulate the foce, check for the angle between them:

```
angle = Math.atan2(A.y - B.y, A.x - B.x);
```

The new velocity for B will be:

```
//We do not consider mass (assuming it is 1)
B.newVel.x = Math.cos(angle) * B.oldVel.x + F * delta;  
B.newVel.y = Math.sin(angle) * B.oldVel.y + F * delta;
```

This is not classic spring behavior as it does not consider the fact that the spring will repel an object if it is too close (closer than the equilibrium point).

If you wish to emulate that, detract a constant `e` from the distance `x` and it will push the object away if it is too near. To make the object stop, you will need to weaken the spring, otherwise it will continue to move near and then away after reaching it's attractor.

Comment: is there any reason why people keep using angles to calculate this, isn't it easier to just subtract one position from annother and then just normalize that, multiply by a value (in this case the force) and add that to the old vector, it should be way less expensive than trigonometry

Comment: @dreta How expensive is normalizing? Last I checked it required a sqrt which is rather expansive. On the other hand, trigonometry can be solved by creating an array of answers in advance since the functions result is locked between -1 and 1 and accuracy beyond 1/1000 is hardly noticeable to the human eye.

Comment: You need to calculate the distance anyway, so it's just a division, besides even if it wasn't, square root is hardware accelerated these days and trigonometry functions aren't

Comment: Can you show reference to that? Yes I suppose this is constructive criticism. I am not sure about the sqrt part. Like I said you can calculate the result of 10,000 different angles for sin and no one will notice you are not calculating. I never noticed this was a bottle neck in any project I worked on.

Comment: i'm not saying this is a big deal, it's just that there's a less expensive way of doing this (unless we are talking about using look-up tables, like you've mentioned), that's why i'm asking if there's any reason why people use angles or is it just a habit, i'm not trying to be rude

Comment: Just a habit. Your comment was constructive.

Comment: I agree with @dreta, The solution would be much clearer using vectors. And You can have a lookup table for sqrt if really needed.Besides you know what they say about early optimisation...

Comment: I think you could only have a lookup for sqrt for a very small range. Unlike sin and cos, it is not locked between -1 and 1.

Comment: Sqrt is similar to arctan in that respect

Comment: annother thing, not trying to nit pick, the equations you edited in don't account for the minus sign in the force equation, also you're calculating force the whole time, that translates to acceleration and that to velocity, so i don't think it's appropriate to mention velocity everywhere like you're calculating that (you aren't), i'm not good with physics though, so i may be wrong, it's a good answer otherwise imho +1

Comment: It takes the minus into assign because I am using A - B instead of B - A. What do you mean by not mentioning velocity?

Comment: nevermind, you assume that mass is one so it's like F = a and you can ommit calculating acceleration before modifying speed, i'm a dummy

Comment: Should the velocity be added to position so the ball moves of should we multiply it? Thanks

Comment: @JSmith If you compute a velocity, then this velocity needs to be multiplied by the time delta and then the result is added to its position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 4):

What you need to implement is Hookes law. This is an equation which calculates the force created by a spring. The equation is;

F=-kx

where x is the how far a way the spring is from its 'natural' or resting length. i.e if a spring has a resting length of 5 meters and is stretched to 8 meters, x is 3 in this case.
k is the spring constant, which controls how 'strong' the spring is. Note there is a minus sign. That is because the force acts in the opposite direction of the direction of stretching (or compression).

Once you know F, you can calculate the acceleration a=F/mass.

you will probably want to include damping in your model, otherwise an will bounce back and forth forever.

Now your equation will be

F=-kx-cv

v is the velocity of the object and c is the amount of damping (bigger values mean the oscillation will stop sooner

Answer (score 2):

Rather than invoking physics, simpler solution would be to constantly adjust their positions to make sure that they are the required distance apart.

```
Vector2 disp=b.pos-a.pos; //displacement between both points

float adj=disp.length()-requiredLength; // how far are we from correct seperation

disp.normalize();

a.pos+=disp*0.01f*adj; //move a towards/away from b by 1% of the discrepancy
b.pos-=disp*0.01f*adj; //move b towards/away from a
```

In this code adjust the 0.01 value to make the objects move quicker or slower.